# Can not install default library in agda

Tags: functional-programming, agda

Trying to follow this guide: https://plfa.github.io/GettingStarted/

On the part after "Check if the Agda standard library was installed correctly" get this:

```
$ agda -v 2 nats.agda
Checking nats (C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\nats.agda).
C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\nats.agda:1,1-21
Failed to find source of module Data.Nat in any of the following
locations:
  C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\Data\Nat.agda
  C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\Data\Nat.lagda
  C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\.stack-work\install\5f9701df\share\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.8.3\Agda-2.6.1.1\lib\prim\Data\Nat.agda
  C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\.stack-work\install\5f9701df\share\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.8.3\Agda-2.6.1.1\lib\prim\Data\Nat.lagda
when scope checking the declaration
  open import Data.Nat
```

Trying to see the location of libraries file:

```
$ agda -l fjdsk Dummy.agda
 Library 'fjdsk' not found.
 Add the path to its .agda-lib file to
   'C:\Users\AuSeR\AppData\Roaming\agda\libraries'
 to install.
 Installed libraries:
   (none)
```

libraries file looks like this:

C:\Users\AuSeR\agda\agda-stdlib\standard-library.agda-lib

defaults like this:

standard-library